# not able to traverse AJAX response

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to send some data to save in database using AJAX request. How can I get all the values using some loop or anything.

I've tried doing dataType and contentType as well. 'application/JSON' in both

My Script in Template

```
var values = {
   answer: [{'age': '21'},{'name': ['abc', 'xyz']}],
   user_id: 11
};

$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'respMap',
   data: values,
   success: function(result) {
       console.log("done");
   },
   error: function () {
       console.log("error");
   }    
});
```

My Views

```
def saveResponseMap(request):
    data = request.POST
    print(data)
return HttpResponse(data)
```

I expected a JSON  but it `answer[0][name]` is coming as `string` in the response `{'answer[0][age]': ['21'], 'answer[1][name][]': ['abc', 'xyz'], 'user_id': ['11']}`

Comment: `dataType` is for the response not the data being sent. contentType is the one you want to use for specifying the the type of data being sent. But you didnt set `data` to json text you gave it an object which by default jquery will transform to x-www-form-encoded format which is what you got. It does not automatically transform objects to json. Set `data:JSON.stringify(values)` when setting contentType to json

Comment: @PatrickEvans, Thanks for that, now I am getting the Header in proper JSON format however I am not able to get the response from my views. Do you by any chance know to can I deal with the response in Django Views?